# Теряется ли возможность обновлять android приложение после переподписывания?

Tags: android

Представим скачавшему не понравился дизайн приложения и он решил его декомпилировать.Изменил фон приложения,потом обратно собрал приложение и подписал его своим ключом.

1. Будет ли у него возможность обновлять это самое приложение через Google Play ? Или пересобранное и переподписанное приложение уже никакого отношения к оригиналу иметь не будет?
2. Если всё-же есть возможность обновлять "форк" apk,то будет ли конфликт при обновлении ? Т.е вернётся ли фон пересобранного приложения на фон оригинала после обновления ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приложения уникально идентифицируются по пакету и по сертификату, которым оно подписано. Засим, при изменении одного из этих параметров обновлений из маркета автоматических не будет. В случае изменения пакета маркет не сможет найти приложение у себя, а в случае изменения подписи - не сможет обновить.

Если пересобрать `APK` с другой подписью и попытаться обновить его приложением с большей версией и другой подписью будет выведено сообщение о конфликте подписей и указано, что текущая версия будет удалена, все её данные потёрты и приложение будет заменено полностью.

Естественно, что все ресурсы приложения (строки, стили etc), будучи частью `APK` файла никак не передаются/не сохраняются между обновлениями. Они содержаться в разных файлах и после замены одного файла другим полностью теряются.

Если вам надо дать возможность смены темы юзерами, то надо писать какие-то параметры в места, которые не затираются при обновлениях. Например в БД или вообще отдельный файл на диске, за пределами папки приложения или вообще на сервер какой-то. В этом случае вам придётся ещё реализовать программное извлечение этих значений и программное применение и к внешнему виду приложения.

С другой стороны есть способ загрузки кода рантайме по ссылке. Для этого делается dex модуль, он скачивается и сохраняется где-то в памяти телефона. После чего используется `PathClassLoader` Но этот способ прямо **запрещён гуглом** к использованию в приложениях для маркета из-за соображений безопасности.

Однако, при наличии определённых навыков, кто-то может поменять пакет (идентификатор) приложения, и даже попытаться выложить его в маркет как *отдельное* приложение.